# How to change cases in a switch statement once one case condition is met?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to figure out how to switch between cases in Javascript/jQuery.  I'm creating a dice game where the player needs to roll the dice until they finish the "Phase".  Once they finish the "Phase" they will move onto the next "Phase" and any previous "Phases" won't interfere with the current "Phase".  There will be several different "Phases" where they start at "Phase 1" and work down to "Phase 2" and so on until the last phase.  Is there any way I can work down the "Phases"?  I'm trying a switch statement here with no success.  If a switch statement won't do the job, what will?

```
//Start of Dice Code
var die1Array = [];
var die2Array = [];
var die3Array = [];

var die1 = function() {
    var roll1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
    if(roll1 === 1) {
        die1Array.push(1);
    }
    else if(roll1 === 2) {
        die1Array.push(2);
    }
    else if(roll1 === 3) {
        die1Array.push(3);
    }
    else if(roll1 === 4) {
        die1Array.push(4);
    }
    else if(roll1 === 5) {
        die1Array.push(5);
    }
    else if(roll1 === 6) {
        die1Array.push(6);
    }
};

var die2 = function() {
    var roll2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
    if(roll2 === 1) {
        die2Array.push(1);
    }
    else if(roll2 === 2) {
        die2Array.push(2);
    }
    else if(roll2 === 3) {
        die2Array.push(3);
    }
    else if(roll2 === 4) {
        die2Array.push(4);
    }
    else if(roll2 === 5) {
        die2Array.push(5);
    }
    else if(roll2 === 6) {
        die2Array.push(6);
    }
};

var die3 = function() {
    var roll3 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
    if(roll3 === 1) {
        die3Array.push(1);
    }
    else if(roll3 === 2) {
        die3Array.push(2);
    }
    else if(roll3 === 3) {
        die3Array.push(3);
    }
    else if(roll3 === 4) {
        die3Array.push(4);
    }
    else if(roll3 === 5) {
        die3Array.push(5);
    }
    else if(roll3 === 6) {
        die3Array.push(6);
    }
};
//End of Dice Code


var main = function() {

    $("#roll").on("click", die1);
    $("#roll").on("click", die2);
    $("#roll").on("click", die3);
    $("#roll").on("click", die4);
    $("#roll").on("click", die5);
    $("#roll").on("click", die6);

    //Where I want to switch between cases.
    //Once Phase 1's condition (the if statement) is met, I want to switch to Phase 2.
    var lvls = 1;
    switch(lvls) {
        case 1:
            alert("Phase 1");
            $("#submit").click(function() {
                if((die1Array.slice(-1)=="1"||die2Array.slice(-1)=="1"||die3Array.slice(-1)=="1")&&(die1Array.slice(-1)=="2"||die2Array.slice(-1)=="2"||die3Array.slice(-1)=="2")&&(die1Array.slice(-1)=="3"||die2Array.slice(-1)=="3"||die3Array.slice(-1)=="3")) {
                    alert("Completed Phase 1: Straight of 3");
                    lvls = 2;
                    return lvls;
                }
                else {
                    alert("Phase 1: Straight of 3.  Not Complete.  Try again.");
                };
            });
            break;

        case 2:
            alert("Phase 2");
            //Phase 2's code
            break;

        //Additional cases/Phases would go here.
        default:
    };

};


$(document).ready(main);
```

Comment: For starters why are you checking the dice roll value in a ton of if/else statements instead of just adding `die1Array.push(roll1)`?

Comment: I also have some images of dice that will show if the condition is met.  Such as: if(roll1===1) {$("#die-1").show);}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your *die#* function you could just push the values without the *if else* part.

```
var die1 = function () {
    var roll1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
    die1Array.push(roll1);
}
```

Or more general:

var die = function (dieArray) {
        dieArray.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1);
   }

Using:

die(die1Array);
  die(die2Array);
  die(die3Array);
  ...

The issue of your current *swithc* is that you bind an event handler function inside a case.

If you want that event handler work only in a particular state, you should set a state variable to save the current state and check this variable in the handler function.

```
var main = function () {
    var diceState = 1;

    $("#submit").click(function() {
            if (diceState === 1) {
                // do something
            }
        });

    switch(lvls) {
    case 1:
          diceState = 1;
          break;

    case 2: 
         diceState = 2;
         break;
    }
```

The other problem you have is that you set the value of *lvls* to 1 in the main function and so you will have only 1 case, the other changes of *lvls* will have no effect at all, even you call *main* again.

If you call *main* more than one time, then you have the problem you're continuosly binding event *onsubmit*, so each time you submit the form, the function handler is called many times.

You should move the *switch* statement in a different function, passing the state variable as parameter, and call each time you want to change the state.

So here an example:

```
// Should be in same scope of the function
// or an attribute of an object to be passed by reference.
var diceState;

var changeState = function (state) {
    switch(state) {
    case 1:
        diceState = 1;
        break;
    ....
    default:
        throw new Error("State " + state + " not supported");
    }
}
```

And is a good practice to use the *default* case to handle unexpected values.

Here a suggestion on how to change your main function:

```
var main = function() {

    var lvls;

    $("#roll").on("click", die1);
    $("#roll").on("click", die2);
    $("#roll").on("click", die3);
    $("#roll").on("click", die4);
    $("#roll").on("click", die5);
    $("#roll").on("click", die6);

    var changeState = function (state) {
        switch(state) {
        case 1:
            alert("Phase 1");
            lvls = state;
            break;

        case 2:
            alert("Phase 2");
            //Phase 2's code
            lvls = state;
            break;

        //Additional cases/Phases would go here.
        default:
        };
    }

    // bind the event handler
    $("#submit").click(function() {
if((die1Array.slice(-1)=="1"||die2Array.slice(-1)=="1"||die3Array.slice(-1)=="1")&&(die1Array.slice(-1)=="2"||die2Array.slice(-1)=="2"||die3Array.slice(-1)=="2")&&(die1Array.slice(-1)=="3"||die2Array.slice(-1)=="3"||die3Array.slice(-1)=="3")) {
                alert("Completed Phase 1: Straight of 3");
                changeState(2);

                // you could not return the vaue here!
                // return lvls; 
            }
            else {
                alert("Phase 1: Straight of 3.  Not Complete.  Try again.");
            };
        });

     changeState(1);

};
```

Comment: It makes sense, but how do I automatically change the case once, lets say, case 1 is met? So, if case 1 if met, it changes to case 2.

Answer (score 0):

Before addressing your question I want to mention your if/else statements:

```
if(roll1 === 1) {
    die1Array.push(1);
}
else if(roll1 === 2) {
    die1Array.push(2);
}
```

If you're going to put the value of `roll1` into `die1Array` regardless of what the value is, why are you checking it first every time? Just do a `die1Array.push(roll1);` and call it a day.

I don't think you even want a switch statement here at all. What are you hoping to achieve with a switch statement?

The logic of your code is essentially this:

```
var main = function() {
    // onclick stuff
    lvls = 1
    switch(lvls){}
}
```

This is going to immediately go into this switch statement with the hard value of 1 you force immediately before it, thus always hitting the first case.

The logic of this seems like it would be better suited to calling various functions. Maybe a function for `phaseTwo(){...}` but a switch statement is primarily used to check the state of an item at a specific point, not for tracking the state over time.

Comment: Your function of phaseTwo(){...} is what I'm looking for, but I can't figure out how to write the functions to make it work like you're saying.  Because, once phaseOne(){...} is met, I want to move onto phaseTwo(){...}  How would you suggest I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Here is some working ES6 code you may find useful.

It defines the names and the verification functions for each of the phases in an array. The `roll` function performs the random generation of the 5 dices (could be any number) a few times, so to give some animation, and then calls back, providing the value of each of the dice.

A global `lvl` variable is then used to find and execute the correct verification function. If this passes, the `lvl` is incremented:

```js
const dieFaces = [null,'&#9856;','&#9857;','&#9858;','&#9859;','&#9860;','&#9861;'];
const DICE_COUNT = 5;
var lvl = 0;
var phases = [
    {
        descr: 'Phase 1: Pair',
        test: function (counts) {
            return counts.some( count => count > 1 );
        }
    },
    {
        descr: 'Phase 2: Three of a Kind',
        test: function (counts) {
            return counts.some( count => count > 2 );
        }
    },
    {
        descr: 'Phase 3: Full House',
        test: function (counts) {
            return counts.some( count => count > 2 ) &&
                   counts.filter( count => count > 1 ).length > 1;
        }
    },
    {
        descr: 'Phase 4: Small Straight',
        test: function (counts) {
            return counts.map( count => count>0 ).join('').indexOf('1111') > -1;
        }
    },
    {
        descr: 'Phase 5: Large Straight',
        test: function (counts) {
            return counts.map( count => count>0 ).join('').indexOf('11111') > -1;
        }
    },
    {
        descr: 'Phase 6: Four of a Kind',
        test: function (counts) {
            return counts.some( count => count > 3 );
        }
    }
];

function roll(callback, rolling = 20) {
    let faces = [];
    let dice = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < DICE_COUNT; i++) {
        let die = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
        dice.push(die);
        faces.push(dieFaces[die]);
    }
    $('#dice').html(faces.join(' '));
    if (!rolling) return callback(dice);
    setTimeout(roll.bind(null, callback, rolling-1), 50);
}

$("#roll").on("click", function () {
    $('#result').text("");
    roll(function (dice) {
        var acc = dice.map( die => 0 );
        dice.forEach( die => ++acc[die] );
        if (phases[lvl].test(acc)) { 
            $('#result').text("Completed " + phases[lvl].descr);
            lvl++;
            $('#phase').text(phases[lvl].descr);
        } else {
            $('#result').text("Try again");
        }
    });
});

$('#phase').text(phases[0].descr);
```

```css
#dice { font-size: 40px }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="phase"></div>
<button id="roll">Roll</button>
<div id="dice"></div>
<div id="result"></div>
```